# Shapefile with a pole inside

Tags: shapefile, polygon-creation, antarctica

I am trying to create a shapefile with an inner and an outer ring. When one of the pole is located inside the polygon, the inner ring is not recognized

Here is a simple example reproducing my problem

```
import shapefile

# Creating the rings
# Outer-ring: Clockwise (as seen from southpole)
# Inner-ring: Counter-clockwise (as seen from southpole)
LAT = -60
lat = -70
outer_ring = [[0  , LAT],[ 60, LAT],[120, LAT],[180, LAT], [240, LAT], [300, LAT],[360, LAT]] 
inner_ring = [[360, lat],[300, lat],[240, lat],[180, lat], [120, lat], [ 60, lat],[0  , lat]]


# Creating the shapefile
shp_file = 'test.shp'
shp = shapefile.Writer(shp_file, shapefile.POLYGON)
shp.field('name', 'C')
shp.poly([inner_ring,outer_ring])
shp.record('test')
shp.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `shp.poly([inner_ring,outer_ring])` is right? might it need to be `shp.poly([outer_ring,inner_ring])`

Comment: @Ian Turton

As far I understand the shapefile, what is important is the orientation of the rings (clockwise for outer-rings, counterclockwise for inner-rings), not their order in the polygon.

In any case, I made the switch and i still to have the same problem

Comment: For shapefile, the order *isn't* important, but for just about every other format it is (an in practice, the outer rings always precede the inner), so following {outer,inner} order is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm as do not use either modules, but the `shapefile` module you import appears to be an old module as highlighted by the document page [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Python%20Shapefile%20Library/). It makes no mention about creating multi-part shapes. I would recommend you use what appears to be a more modern version by the same author called [pyshp](https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/) which has superior supporting documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Two comments:

* I have no problem to create multi-part polygon when the poles (south or north) are not included

* As far I understand, shapefile and PyShp are not two different modules. [pyshape]( https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) is available in PyShp. I actually follow the examples provided in the links that you shared ([PyShp]( https://pypi.org/project/pyshp)) to create my script